# how to give multiple runtime permissions in android Q programmatically

Tags: android

```java
 private void CheckPermissions() {
        RxPermissions.getInstance(SpalshActivity.this)
                .request(
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                )
                .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        initialize(aBoolean);
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initialize(boolean isAppInitialized) {
        if (isAppInitialized) {
            Thread background = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            background.start();

        } else {
            //If one Of above permission not grant show alert (force to grant permission)
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpalshActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            builder.setMessage("All permissions necessary");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    CheckPermissions();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static void PermissionCheck(Context context) {
        int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 20;
        if (!AppUtils.isPremissionsGranted(context)) {
            AppUtils.requestAppPermissions(new
                            String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS, context);
        }

    }
```

Comment: We can check multiple permissions using String array.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you are having any issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                // FIXME: Handle this case the user denied to grant the permissions
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            // TODO: Take care of this case later
            break;
    }
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    List<String> requiredPermissions = new ArrayList<>();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requiredPermissions.add( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA )
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requiredPermissions.add( Manifest.permission.CAMERA );
    }

    if (!requiredPermissions.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
                requiredPermissions.toArray( new String[]{} ),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS );
    }
}
```

Comment: private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS = 0; and from onCreateactivity()  call requestPermissions();